# How do I treat JMS queue as a temporary storage?

Tags: java, jms, temporary-objects

I want to be able to pull and insert messages to and from a queue. Is it possible to leverage JMS features for this, or should I need create a custom data structure for this?

Please let me know if there is any other specific design pattern for a temporary storage.

**Update**:
Since many asking for more detail, so here it is. My requirement is to store a message in a queue from which multiple clients can push the data to, and also pull the data back from it as and when required. This queue should be available to multiple clients. One message should be processed only once and if client is not able to process the data then message should return back to the queue.

Comment: JMS API is sufficient to do your task. But, Queues are not expected to use as temporary storage but rather to pass messages asynchronously.

Comment: @Indoknight thanks for your reply, but my requirement is of a temporary storage. Is there any other design pattern or component available for the same?

Comment: If depends on the scope of your storage. In Java, you can use static variable for application scope and instance variables for object level scope.

Comment: @gurvinder372 it might be better if you describe a little bit more what is the scenario you have

Comment: @jbx I have added more details into my question. Please have a look

Comment: @gurvinder372 Your requirement seems to be exactly that of a JMS queue. It is still not clear how the 'temporary storage' and 'custom data structure' come into the story. In my answer I pretty much described what you can do regarding data structures and temporary storage.

Comment: @jbx Can a client fetch from queue only when it wants to? Is it possible to treat 'receive from queue' same as a 'fetch from queue'?

Comment: @gurvinder372 Yes. You can call `receive()` synchronously when you want, i.e. when you are ready to process the next message. Alternatively you can let the queue library call you when there is a message waiting for you by implementing the MessageListener interface. Both are possible and available for you to use depending on what your situation is. However, the `MessageListener.onMessage()` method is not called with the next message until the session has completed the last call, so if serial processing or overloading is what worries you, the JMS Session ensures you will only get one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are asking multiple things in one question, so it might benefit you to clarify a little the individual points you need answered.

Yes, it is possible to have JMS used as a 'temporary' storage, but it depends on what you mean by that and what you need. Most JMS providers (such as ActiveMQ) allow you to do the following things on queues:

- Set a queue to durable (i.e. store on disk and if the queue gets restarted all messages are there) or non-durable (i.e. do not store on disk and if the queue gets restarted there will be no messages).
- You can set an expiry time on messages, so that if they are not picked up on time they are discarded.

This depends on what you are referring to as 'temporary storage'. A JMS queue is not a database, its a messaging system.

Regarding data structures, you can serialize both normal Java Objects in an `ObjectMessage` and also text messages with the `TextMessage`. So you can pass through XML, JSON, CSV or whatever you want. You can also include special headers which you can use for routing or other meta-information associated with the message. Again depends on what you mean by 'custom data structure'. You can also send a raw `BytesMessage`, or a `MapMessage` (key-value pairs), or a `StreamMessage` with different data types inside it one after the other.

If you need temporary storage in the literal sense, maybe you should look at embedded databases such as Derby or HSQLDB. I think they also have configurations to state whether data should stay in memory or go to disk after it gets too large.

Comment: can you please share a pointer or working example for the comment you have given above? Thanks

Comment: @gurvinder372 For which comment? I mentioned lots of stuff :) What do you actually need to know?

Comment: Yes but thats also long and just too abstract. What do you want to achieve exactly? Asynchronous receive? Synchronous receive? And which JMS implementation did you choose? Are you using any frameworks such as Spring?

Comment: Well the Oracle specification is just a specification, it doesn't offer you an implementation. You need to choose one of the JMS providers available such as Apache ActiveMQ (unless you're using a JEE application server). If you search online for `JMS synchronous receive` you'll get loads of examples. I just tried it and this one was at the top http://effectivemessaging.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/jms-synchronous-message-consumption.html . At least do some effort to find things yourself!